# Appmetrics - Module Initialization error while running the lambda node Js function in console

Tags: node.js, lambda, elastic-stack

Added the following lines in the index.js file,

```
var config = {
host: 'http://localhost:9200'
}
var appmetrics = require('appmetrics-elk').monitor(config);
```

When trying to test the lambda function it says module initialization error, please find the stack trace for the error

```
 {
 "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/appmetrics-elk/node_modules/appmetrics/appmetrics.node: invalid ELF header",
 "errorType": "Error",
 "stackTrace": [
 "Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)",
 "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
 "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
 "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
 "require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
 "Object. (/var/task/node_modules/appmetrics-elk/node_modules/appmetrics/index.js:27:13)",
 "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
 "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
 "Module.load (module.js:343:32)"
 ]}
```

Using the latest appmetrics-elk version.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any information about what kind of environment you're attempting to run this in, so this is a bit of a stab in the dark:

According to [ELF Header or installation issue with bcrypt in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604334/elf-header-or-installation-issue-with-bcrypt-in-docker-container) (2nd answer), this can happen when you've built your application locally and then attempt to get it to run in a container or cloud environment like Bluemix or Docker without clearing out your `node_modules` directory.

`appmetrics-elk` has a dependency on `appmetrics` which has native C code in it. When you `npm i appmetrics-elk` you will end up with a `node_modules/appmetrics-elk/node_modules/appmetrics/appmetrics.node` that is specific to your environment. If you then upload this to the cloud or to a container i.e a different environment, the binary `appmetrics.node` won't work there.

The solution is to just upload your application without a `node_modules` directory and include a dependency on `appmetrics-elk` in your `package.json`. The container should then build an `appmetrics.node` that works in that environment.